# Getting more x-axis ticks/labels for large time series plot pdf export

Tags: r, plot, time-series, zoo, timeserieschart

I am plotting a very large time series (200.000 observations).
But I want to look at every day in detail and scroll through it day by day.
That is why I am exporting it as .pdf with width=500.

Here is the code ( x is a multivariate zoo time series)

```
pdf(file= "myPlot.pdf", width=500, height = 20 )

plot(x,plot.type = "multiple", nc = 1, col =c("green"), 
    ylim = list(c(0,25), c(0.05,1),c(4,10), c(700,1000),
                c(100,500),c(0,2), c(0,3600)))
dev.off()
```

This works good so far. I can zoom into the pdf and then scroll through the series.

Problem is now, I have no accurate x-axis ticks / labels.
I would like to have at least daily labels. But I get one label per month.

I tried now the following:
    pdf(file= "myPlot.pdf", width=500, height = 20 )

```
plot(x,plot.type = "multiple", nc = 1, col =c("green"), xaxt="n",
     ylim = list(c(0,25), c(0.05,1),c(4,10), c(700,1000),
                c(100,500),c(0,2), c(0,3600)))
axis(1,time(x))
dev.off()
```

But now no x axis appears in the pdf at all.

Comment: What class is "x" or equivalently should `time(x)` be a meaningful expression? What packages have you loaded?

Comment: x is a multivariate zoo series, I will add this to the question

Comment: R zoo objects are fairly complex. Since you have not gotten much interest yet, you might consider editing your question to include a minimal but complete example. That is after all what is requested of SO questioners.